# Combining 2 SQL queries from a WCF service

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

Basically  I don't know how to  query  my database so it returns only fields containing `username` and `date`. 
I can query them separately but not together.

However there's no option for `AND` in intellisense.

These are the 2 queries:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<TimeData> GetUsersSpecific(string DateToSearch, string NameToSearch)
{
    TimeDataEntities3 e = new TimeDataEntities3();
    var x  = (from q in e.TimeDatas 
              where q.Date.Contains(DateToSearch) 
              select q);
    var y  = (from r in e.TimeDatas 
              where r.Username.Contains(NameToSearch)
              select r);
    return ();        
}
```

But really i'd like something like:

```
var y = (from r in e.TimeDatas 
         where r.Username.Contains(NameToSearch) 
           AND where r.Date.Contains(Datetosearch)  
         select r);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `&&` operator instead of `AND` one:

```
var timeData = from t in e.TimeDatas
               where t.Date.Contains(DateToSearch)
                  && t.Username.Contains(NameToSearch)
               select t;
```

Now you have access to `Date` and `Username` properties through `timeData`.

Comment: I tried && before and it didn't work, but it worked fine now. So guess it was me being stupid  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `AND where` by `&&` in your expression?

```
var y  = (from r in e.TimeDatas 
           where r.Username.Contains(NameToSearch) 
             && r.Date.Contains (Datetosearch)  
           select r);
```